# DateTime with Hijri Calender - 30/02 Always throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

There is a constructor overload that takes

```
new DateTime(1436, 2, 30, new System.Globalization.HijriCalender());
```

But the above will always throw an exception, regardless of year. I think this is because it "thinks" this is Gregorian date and hence February cannot be 30 days???

Answer (score 1):

The year 1436 is a [leap year and in Hijri calendar](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System.Globalization/types/HijriCalendar.html) the February month has 29 days. That is the reason why you are getting the exception.

[image]

Comment: @user3441905:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have created a loop from 1436 to 1366 and every time it throws the same exception, regardless of year

Comment: @user3441905:- Check the link which I have added in my answer. It shows that the number of days are either 29 or 30 for the consecutive months. So its more of related to that!

Comment: The url you put states that .net Calender has always 29 days in Month 2. This is a drawback in .net, because it sometimes 30 and sometimes 29. But not always like they did.

Comment: @user3441905:- Indeed but now most of the time Gregorian calendar is used and followed!

Comment: As programmer yes, but for client this a requirement

Comment: @user3441905 Clearly you can't use the .NET structure then. Perhaps you'll find some use of NodaTime.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HijriCalender` always fails. But .net also provides `UmAlQuraCalendar` which is also a HijriCalender but doesn't throw that exception !!